# Challenge with Ordering Django Signals and Celery Tasks for Group Operations

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery, signals

I'm facing an issue in my Django project where the execution order of Django signals and Celery tasks is causing complications, particularly in managing group operations asynchronously. Specifically, when there's a change in group administrators triggering the update_group_admins signal, the create request task (create_group_async) should ideally be executed before the tasks for adding or removing group members (add_group_admins_async and remove_group_admins_async). However, despite my meticulous planning, the sequence of execution remains incorrect, leading to errors and inconsistencies in the system.

To address this issue, I've attempted various approaches to reorder the tasks and signals within my codebase. My expectation was that by ensuring the correct sequence of execution, the create request task (create_group_async) would be processed before the tasks for adding or removing group members (add_group_admins_async and remove_group_admins_async). However, despite my efforts, the execution sequence remains erroneous, and I haven't been able to achieve the desired outcome.